# How to generate a new Angular 4 project instead of creating generating Angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

I recently just installed Angular on my Ubuntu 16.04 computer following the documentation found [here](https://cli.angular.io/). But when i generate a new Angular project, it generates Angular 6.

How do i generate specific angular 4 project?

Comment: If you can you should use the latest version available it will save you the trouble of updating later

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can following these steps to generate an Angular 4 project

```
> npm remove -g @angular/cli
> npm install -g @angular/cli@1.4.10
> ng --version
  @angular/cli: 1.4.10
> ng new myangular4
```

Assuming that you already have angular cli installed in your system, the steps above will remove the current angular cli installed an will be replaced by an angular cli that can generate Angular 4.

Answer (score 0):

Try the follow command in your project folder,

```
npm install @angular/cli@wished.version.here
```

Read the [changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

And if you want to change the CLI version globally then use `-g` in `npm install` command.

Another way to do is that

1.Remove/Rename the `node_modules` folder of your project.

2.Change the `dependencies` in your package.json file to

```
 "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/compiler": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/core": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/forms": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/http": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/tsc-wrapped": "^4.4.6",
        "rxjs": "5.4.0",
        "zone.js": "0.8.12"
    },
```

3. Then run command 'npm install` in the folder where you have created your app.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to do following things to create an app with your choice:**

**Step 1.** Set up the Development Environment:

> You need to set up your development environment before you can do anything. Install Node.js and npm if they are not already on your machine.

**Step 2:**  Then install the **Angular CLI** globally.

**`> npm install -g @angular/cli@1.4.*`**

**Step 3:** Create a new project

**`> ng new my-app`**

**Step 4:** Serve the application:

**`> cd my-app`**

**`> ng serve --open`**

The above app will be in angular 4.